# Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] blank when using ASP.NET wildcard application mapping

Tags: asp.net, wildcard-mapping

When I set up wildcard application maps so that asp.net handles requests (setting executable path to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`) `LOGON_USER` is blank when I access a page via `site.com/directory/` - `site.com/directory/default.aspx` returns the correct `LOGON_USER` value.

How can I fix this without needing to take off application maps?

Simple test:

```
<%# Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] %>
```

Results in `DOMAIN\UserName` when application maps not set up, but a blank string when they are.

Edit:

The site uses Forms authentication for administration, but I need to do LDAP queries based on the currently logged in user (and to search Active Directory) - anonymous access is turned off and Windows Integrated Authentication turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that before, and I almost always wildcard map, but is there any reason you're not using Request.User (or the Page's User helper property) instead of the string-based variable?  I'm not sure if that'll help, but it is at least more safe from typoes.

Comment: No typos, it just doesn't work with application mapping on. No such thing as Request.User... User.Identity.Name returns a blank string.

Comment: Ok, sorry, cannot replicate your problem.